# I updated Sophos now I am getting these errors popping up repeatedly

Tags: macos

How can  I get rd of these pop up error messages, I have deleted the Sophos Antivirus but still I am getting these popups, where is it coming from ?

I am using sierra OS on mac book pro 2013 edition.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Your title & question body don't match... one says update, the other says delete.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Golden Rule - don't try to just "delete" an antivirus, they don't like it.

Use the Uninstaller - there is [was] one in the Applications folder. If you deleted that too, then you'll need to re-download it from [Sophos](https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/121206)

Note: If you have a business install, it will be protected by a Tamper Protection  layer & will need the password, which is not the same as your login/admin password.

Ref: [Sophos Anti-Virus for Mac: How to uninstall](https://community.sophos.com/kb/en-us/120838)